# How to determine the name of an egg for a Python package on Github?

Tags: python, pip, egg, distribute

I know [I can install](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html#git) with

```
$ pip install -e git+https://git.repo/some_pkg#egg=SomePackage
```

but -- when I'm trying to use somebody else's package -- how do I determine what the name of the egg is?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Look at the git repo, find the `setup.py`, `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml` file in the root and find what name has been set.

- In `setup.py`, look for the `name` keyword in the `setup()` function call.
- In `setup.cfg`, look for the `name` entry under the `[metadata]` section.
- If there is only a `pyproject.toml` file, then look for a `[tool.poetry]` or `[tool.flit.metadata]` or `[project]` section, and the `name` entry under that section. (Which section exactly depends on the packaging tool used; [flint](https://flit.pypa.io/en/latest/pyproject_toml.html) and [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/) expect different sections and there may be other projects using `pyproject.toml` to create Python packages in future).

For example, the Pyramid project has a [`setup.py` file](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/1e439035e41da3767acbcae79689fb05dfdeb317/setup.py#L66-L67), which has:

```
setup(
  name='pyramid',
```

so you'd use:

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid.git#egg=pyramid
```

Or, if you look at the [FastAPI repository](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi), then you'd find a [`pyproject.toml` file](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/146f57b8f70c5757dc20edc716dba1b96936a8d6/pyproject.toml#L5-L6) with:

```
[tool.flit.metadata]
module = "fastapi"
```

and so you'd use

```
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi.git#egg=fastapi
```

Comment: Could you explain what is `egg` and why it's needed? I tried to search for it but couldn't find any explanation.

Comment: @SanghyunLee: The [Python egg format](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs) is a distribution format and standard for tracking what is installed. The `#egg=<name>` part tells `pip` under what name the project is installed so it can determine if you already have an existing installation, etc.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was something specific to `pipenv` as I found this thread through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201515/pipenv-requires-an-egg-fragment-for-version-controlled-dependencies-warning-w that's why I couldn't search for what it is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: name could also be elsewhere rather than in setup.py., like in setup.cfg

Comment: @Goku: my answer was originally written before setup.cfg files were a thing. I've updated the answer to cover those, plus pyproject.toml files. Thanks for pointing out my answer was no longer as complete as it could be!

Comment: @MartijnPieters No problem- thank you for updating the answer! I just now noticed it was an old question.

Comment: make sure to put 'git+...' in double quotes. it can save you time searching for the error