# "pipenv requires an #egg fragment for version controlled dependencies" warning when installing the BlueJeans meeting API client

Tags: python, pip, egg, pipenv, bluejeans

Adapting the instructions from https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings/tree/master/libs/python#pip-install, in a `pipenv shell` I'm trying to run

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

> ⠋WARNING: pipenv requires an #egg fragment for version controlled dependencies. Please install remote dependency in the form git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git#egg=.

Here is the full command and response:

```
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$ pipenv install git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo
Installing git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo...
⠋WARNING: pipenv requires an #egg fragment for version controlled dependencies. Please install remote dependency in the form git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git#egg=<package-name>.
ABORTING INSTALL... You will have to reinstall any packages that failed to install.
You may have to manually run pipenv lock when you are finished.
```

How do I get the `egg` for this package? Or even better, how could I disbable the requirement to specify an egg?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Martijn Pieters in [How to determine the name of an egg for a Python package on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638929/how-to-determine-the-name-of-an-egg-for-a-python-package-on-github) describes how to determine the egg: look up the `name` argument to the `setup()` function in the package's `setup.py`. From https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings/blob/master/libs/python/setup.py, this is `BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi` in this case. So the following works:

```
(lucy-web-CVxkrCFK) bash-3.2$ pipenv install git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo#egg=BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
Installing git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo#egg=BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi...
⠇Warning: You installed a VCS dependency in non-editable mode. This will work fine, but sub-dependencies will not be resolved by $ pipenv lock.
  To enable this sub-dependency functionality, specify that this dependency is editable.
Collecting BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi from git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo#egg=BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
  Cloning https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git (to revision pip-repo) to /private/var/folders/dc/nv4yxcrd0zqd2dtxlj281b740000gn/T/pip-install-s0g6q9m5/BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.15 in /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (2018.4.16)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi) (2.6.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/dc/nv4yxcrd0zqd2dtxlj281b740000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-adn35yq2/wheels/9b/3f/9d/57d42cddf6b678af2c5d2c805a74b1f35102ab62d4da6f5d4e
Successfully built BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
Installing collected packages: BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi
Successfully installed BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi-1.0.0

Adding git+https://github.com/bluejeans/api-rest-meetings.git@pip-repo#egg=BlueJeansMeetingsRestApi to Pipfile's [packages]...
Pipfile.lock (7950e0) out of date, updating to (584b28)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Updated Pipfile.lock (584b28)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (584b28)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 80/80 — 00:00:10
```

Comment: I had to put quotes around the git+.... part and then it worked. thanks!