# Unable to install ccxt.pro via pipenv - pipenv requires an #egg fragment for version controlled dependencies

Tags: python-3.7, pipenv, ccxt

I try to install `ccxt.pro` via `pipenv`. I usually use python `venv` module to create virtual environment but I try to work with pipenv too.

In `ccxt.pro` [documentation](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/ccxt.pro.install#python), package should be installed via pip3 over https or ssh. Via github user and password I am able to install it.

When I tried to install this library over `pipenv`, I receive `Installation Failed` error:

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/kroitor/ccxt.pro.git#subdirectory=python
Installing git+https://github.com/kroitor/ccxt.pro.git#subdirectory=python…
WARNING: pipenv requires an #egg fragment for version controlled dependencies. Please 
install remote dependency in the form git+https://github.com/kroitor/ccxt.pro.git#egg=<package-name>.
✘ Installation Failed
```

I install all dependencies from [setup.py](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/setup.py) but the problem persist. Triead to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638929/how-to-determine-the-name-of-an-egg-for-a-python-package-on-github) but it get stucked on `Installing...`.

**Questions**:

1. How can I install ccxt.pro via pipenv?
2. Why am I not able to install it the same way like with `pip install` command?